# dotnet build with profile

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

Before I can use msbuild command in command line and pass the profile as a parameter. Is this currently supported in `dotnet cli` or is there a new way to build projects/solutions in .net core projects?

Comment: Have you run dotnet build --help ?  That will show you the build options available.  Do you have a question about any of the available build options?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "profile"? As in "Debug" or "Release"?

Comment: Not debug or release. In msbuild, you can specify the profile which will read the profile(XML file). The profile contains configurations/settings for the build artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, the dotnet cli is now mostly using msbuild to do the actual work (excluding dotnet new and dotnet run). So if you're doing a dotnet build, it's actually using msbuild internally.

You can still use msbuild parameters when using the dotnet cli, you need to use the following:

```
dotnet msbuild <options>
```

One option is /property:n=v which passes in your property name/value pairs directly to msbuild as you used to do with msbuild itself. You can also continue to use semi-colons between pairs, e.g.:

```
dotnet msbuild /property:WarningLevel=4;Configuration=Release
```

Comment: this was made available again when .NET core went back to *.csproj from project.json.